# Javascript OnClick before submit button

Tags: javascript, forms

Im having an issue getting some bit of code to run before the page submits.

When i change the return value to true to submit the form, the code above doesn't run. The way it is now, the code runs and the page is refreshed. I want to pass a true variable to submit the form Any ideas?

```
    function buildMessageC() {

    //Create an ePOS-Print Builder object
    var builder = new epson.ePOSBuilder();
    //Create a print document
    builder.addTextLang('en')
    builder.addTextSmooth(true);
    builder.addTextFont(builder.FONT_A);
    builder.addTextSize(1, 1);
    builder.addText(document.getElementById('receipt').textContent);
    builder.addFeedLine(1);
    builder.addCut(builder.CUT_FEED);
    //Acquire the print document
    var request = builder.toString();

    //Set the end point address
    var address = 'http://192.168.1.69/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=counter_printer&timeout=10000';
    //Create an ePOS-Print object
    var epos = new epson.ePOSPrint(address);

    //Send the print document
    epos.send(request);

    return false;
```

The form button

```
        <sf:form onsubmit="return buildMessageC()">
            <input class="addToOrderButton button blue large expand" value="Place Order" name="_eventId_placeOrder" type="submit"/>
        </sf:form>
```

Clarification

```
   function doSubmit(){
    buildMessageC();
    return false;
}  gives me print out and reloads the same page not submiting the form                                                                                                             

   function doSubmit(){
    buildMessageC();
    return true;
} doesn't print yet submits the form
```

Comment: You want to run that request and also submit the form? Does that epos framework have some sort of complete event?

Comment: Yes. No everything in the documentations ends with epos.send(request) which prints out a receipt.

Comment: Well if that call is making an asynchronous call, it needs to have a complete method in order to know when to submit the form.

Comment: do you need to add an action attribute to your form tag? (guessing, have not worked with epos)

Comment: i update the question